# Laravel как сделать join и присвоить полю имя?

Tags: php, laravel

```
    public function getAllTeams()
{
    $teams = $this->select()
        ->leftJoin('country', 'team.country_id', '=', 'country.id')
        ->get(['country.name']);
    return $teams;
}
```

Мне нужно получить поле `country.name`. В таблице `teams` есть поле `name`, и в таблице `country`, в итоге я получаю ненужное мне поле из таблицы `country`, а поле `name` из таблицы `teams` перетирается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $teams = $this->select('team.id', 'team.name', 'country.name as country_name', 'team.logo', 'team.cost')
        ->leftJoin('country', 'team.country_id', '=', 'country.id')
        ->get();
    return $teams;
```